# I just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04.1 LTS & now cannot connect to my vpn

Tags: upgrade, openvpn

Here's the error that I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File “usr/local/bin/protonvpn”, line 7, in <module>
        from protonvpn_cli.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘protonvpn_cli’
```

Comment: this is the msg. I get when trying to open up the vpn after upgrading to 20.04.1LTS

Comment: Hi Kunjabihari! Am I correct in assuming you're using a specific software supplied by Proton VPN to establish the connection? If so, have you tried reinstalling said software? It sounds like it got uninstalled with the update to 20.04.

Comment: how to reinstall the software?

Comment: Follow the instructions here to uninstall/install the Proton VPN app: https://protonvpn.com/support/official-linux-client/

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
protonvpn : Depends: proton-cli but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Comment: No module named 'protonvpn_cli

Comment: There are currently two different versions of the ProtonVPN Linux client around, the older Python-based one and a more recent one they just released. You should be able to install both, but it seems you had the Python version before, it's installation instructions can be found [here](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-vpn-tool/).

Comment: Thank, @Sebastian! I added the instructions for removing the Python-based client to my answer.

Comment: looks like I'm almost there
if only I could remember my login name

Comment: no end to the mystery!
finally managed a successful login

Comment: then, got this:
Login successful
:$ sudo protonvpn c
[sudo password]
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/protonvpn", line 7, in <module>
  from protonvpn_cli.cli import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'protonvpn_cli.cli' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/protonvpn_cli/cli.py)

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you're using the Proton VPN app to connect. It is likely that during your upgrade to 20.04 some parts of that app got removed. Reinstall the app as follows:

1. First uninstall the Proton VPN app from your system. If you've been using the Python-based community version, type: `protonvpn configure` and select `7) Purge Configuration.` and then type `sudo pip3 uninstall protonvpn-cli` or `pip3 uninstall protonvpn-cli`. If you've been using the official client, remove it with `sudo apt purge protonvpn`. Depending on which version you have been using, not every command is going to work. No worries, just run dem all to be sure.
2. Then run `sudo apt autoremove` to clean up any leftover packages.
3. Follow the step by step guide on the [Proton VPN website](https://protonvpn.com/support/official-linux-client/) in order to install the VPN client.
4. Connect to the VPN as described in the link above.